# Does requests.session expires if remained idle?

Tags: python, request, urllib3

I am using a request.session()  in a retry request function. I would like to know how long the session lasts. If the `session` object remains idle for some time,  would that expire after some time?

```
def create_requests_retry_session(
        retries=app.config["MAX_RETRY_FOR_SESSION"],
        backoff_factor=app.config["BACKOFF_FACTOR"]):
    """
    implement failure mechanism while calling microservices to avoid system alert
    using parameters like a time limit to get a response. This function will attempt 3 times
    per session
    retries: Defaults to MAX_RETRY_FOR_SESSION
    backoff_factor: how long the processes will sleep between failed requests.
    Defaults to BACKOFF_FACTOR {backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total
    retries} - 1)). If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then sleep() will sleep for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, …] between
    retries. 1 second the successive sleeps will be 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256. 2 seconds - 1, 2, 4,
    8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 10 seconds - 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560
    :return: Session object
    """
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(total=retries, backoff_factor=backoff_factor, method_whitelist=frozenset(['POST']))
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    return session
```

I am using the session object from the above function as session.post()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session will automatically attempt to do keep-alive for as long as possible (unless explicitly disabled), until it's closed. Any timeout will be server-imposed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what  does ` timeout will be server imposed` mean?

Comment: I believe it means that sometimes your server will kill long running processes, and that the session will try to remain alive so long as your computer allows it to be.